# keep the signed value that has minimal absolute value in two matrix in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

In OpenCV, I have two matrix One and Two which are the same size. I want to find the signed value that has minimal absolute value in both matrix and keep it in matrix One. For this, I use following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < One.rows; ++i)
{
    p=One.ptr<float>(i);
    p_two = Two.ptr<float>(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < One.cols; ++j)
    {
        if(fabsf(p_two[j])<fabsf(p[j])) 
             p[j] = p_two[j];
    }
}
```

This code seems to be the bottleneck in my program. Does anyone know how to improve the performance? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have not tested this yet in terms of speed, but in general you could replace your loops by the following line:

Two.copyTo(one, cv::abs(Two) < cv::abs(One));

Comment: This code **can't** be the bottleneck of your program. You need to profile it better

Comment: It may be related with accessing a lot of different, non-consecutive memory segments to read the matrix elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not the bottleneck of your program. It's indeed very fast. You need to profile your code to see where the actual bottleneck is.

---

You can optimize it a little in case your matrices are continuous (which is very often in practice), like:

```
int rows = one.rows;
int cols = one.cols;
if (one.isContinuous() && two.isContinuous())
{
    cols = rows * cols;
    rows = 1;
}

for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
{
    float* pone = one.ptr<float>(r);
    float* ptwo = two.ptr<float>(r);
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
    {
        if (fabs(ptwo[c]) < fabs(pone[c]))
        {
            pone[c] = ptwo[c];
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here a small evaluation also against the good alternative method proposed by @s1h in the comments:

```
two.copyTo(one, abs(two) < abs(one));
```

**Time (in ms)**

```
Size:           Yuanhao         s1h             Miki
[3 x 3]         0.000366543     0.117294        0.000366543
[10 x 10]       0.00109963      0.0157614       0.00109963
[100 x 100]     0.0964009       0.139653        0.112529
[1280 x 720]    8.70577         11.0267         8.65372
[1000 x 1000]   9.66538         13.5068         9.02026
[1920 x 1080]   16.5681         26.9706         15.7412
[4096 x 3112]   104.423         135.629         102.595
[5000 x 5000]   196.124         277.457         187.203
```

You see that your method is very fast. Mine is a little bit faster. @s1h is slower, but more concise and easy to read.

**Code**
You can evaulate the results on your PC with this:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    vector<Size> sizes{ Size(3, 3), Size(10, 10), Size(100, 100), Size(1280, 720), Size(1000, 1000), Size(1920, 1080), Size(4096, 3112), Size(5000, 5000) };

    cout << "Size: \t\tYuanhao \ts1h \t\tMiki" << endl;

    for (int is = 0; is < sizes.size(); ++is)
    {
        Size sz = sizes[is];

        cout << sz << "\t";

        Mat1f img1(sz);
        randu(img1, Scalar(-100), Scalar(100));

        Mat1f img2(sz);
        randu(img2, Scalar(-100), Scalar(100));

        {
            Mat1f one = img1.clone();
            Mat1f two = img2.clone();

            double tic = double(getTickCount());

            for (int r = 0; r < one.rows; ++r)
            {
                float* pone = one.ptr<float>(r);
                float* ptwo = two.ptr<float>(r);
                for (int c = 0; c < one.cols; ++c)
                {
                    if (fabs(ptwo[c]) < fabs(pone[c]))
                    {
                        pone[c] = ptwo[c];
                    }
                }
            }

            double toc = (double(getTickCount()) - tic) * 1000. / getTickFrequency();
            cout << toc << " \t";
        }


        {
            Mat1f one = img1.clone();
            Mat1f two = img2.clone();

            double tic = double(getTickCount());

            two.copyTo(one, abs(two) < abs(one));

            double toc = (double(getTickCount()) - tic) * 1000. / getTickFrequency();
            cout << toc << " \t";
        }


        {
            Mat1f one = img1.clone();
            Mat1f two = img2.clone();

            double tic = double(getTickCount());

            int rows = one.rows;
            int cols = one.cols;
            if (one.isContinuous() && two.isContinuous())
            {
                cols = rows * cols;
                rows = 1;
            }

            for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
            {
                float* pone = one.ptr<float>(r);
                float* ptwo = two.ptr<float>(r);
                for (int c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
                {
                    if (fabs(ptwo[c]) < fabs(pone[c]))
                    {
                        pone[c] = ptwo[c];
                    }
                }
            }

            double toc = (double(getTickCount()) - tic) * 1000. / getTickFrequency();
            cout << toc << " \t";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! It is really helpful. My profiler tells me the line **if(fabs(p_two[j])<fabs(p_one[j]))** is the bottleneck. I think it might be the problem because the two float must be turn into absolute value and then compared. I wonder if it is possible to avoid fabs by something like `if((p_two[j]<p_one[j] && p_two[j]>0) || (p_two[j]>p_one[j] && p_two[j]<0) ` But the case that one is positive and the other is negative would be a problem. Any idea?

Comment: What are you trying to optimize? Why are a few ms so important to you?

Comment: Hi Miki, the thing is that we need to do millions of this operations. That is why we want to optimize this. Consider the matrix is 1000X1000 and we do 100 times iterations. This becomes a problem.

Comment: Ok, that's reasonable. Well, there isn't much you can gain from this snippet. I see a couple of options: 1) re-arrange your algorithm, so that you a) perform less comparison, b) re-use already computed data somehow, c) use uchar instead of float; or 2) parallelize your code doing d) each of this operation in parallel on multiple matrices (OpenCV has support for this with `ParallelLoopBody`), or e) single matrix operations with SIMD instructions using SSE to speedup the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot! b) is a good option. I also consider to save the absolute value and just do comparison. Other options are reasonable, but currently I could not get it done. BTW, I am trying to optimize the code at [curvature filter](https://github.com/YuanhaoGong/CurvatureFilter), maybe you could give me some ideas to improve its performance? Thanks in advance!